# Get the users tag relationship through posts

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm building a Laravel Blog application for learning purposes.
In this applications I have posts that are associated with one users, and tags that are associated with posts (and later videos).

The database structure that I have:

**users**

```
- id
...
```

**posts**

```
- id
- user_id
...
```

**tags**

```
- id
...
```

**taggables**

```
- id
- tag_id
- taggable_id // post id or video id
- taggable_type // App\Models\Post or App\Models\Video
```

The models that I have:

**User.php**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

**Post.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Tag.php**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Post::class, 'taggable')->withTimestamps();
}
```

The problem is that I want to get all the tags that is associated with the given user's posts.

I thought that this can be done with relationships, but somehow I can't do it. Is there a way to do this with relationships? Or it can't be done?

The solution that I found:
**User.php**

```
public function tags()
{
    $posts = $this->posts()
        ->pluck('id');

    return Tag::whereHas('posts', function(Builder $query) use ($posts) {
        $query->whereIn('taggable_id', $posts);
    })->get();
}
```

This solution returns a collection of data, not a relationship. Is there a way to return a relationship in this case? Or is it not possible to make relationships in such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

I dont tested it but you could do something like

```
public function postTags()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Tag::class, Post::class, 'taggable_id')->where('taggable_type', array_search(static::class, Relation::morphMap()) ?: static::class);
}
```

This is a normal hasManyThrough and you have to build the polymorphic logic by your self.

To Explain your query

```
public function tags()
{
    $posts = $this->posts()
        ->pluck('id');

    // The use of Tag::whereHas returns a Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Query not an relation like HasMany, HasOne or like in your case a HasManyThrough
    return Tag::whereHas('posts', function(Builder $query) use ($posts) {
        $query->whereIn('taggable_id', $posts);
    })
    ->get(); // The get at the end sends the query to your database, so you receive a collection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem here I have Same type of database relation.
In my Category_model table I am storing

- category_id
- model_type
- model_id

Inside the Category model I have following code :

```
 public function article()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Article::class, 'model', 'category_model', 'category_id');
}
```

and inside controller :

```
  // Show posts by Category
public function ShowArticleByCategory($category)
{
    $cat  = Category::where('name', $category)->firstOrFail();
    $posts = $cat->article()->get()->sortByDesc('id');
    return view('front.pages.show-by-category', compact('posts'));
}
```

This will give me all the posts that belongs selected/Supplied Category.

Hope this help you will get the idea of getting data from polymorphic relations.

All the parameters tha can be passed inside the relations are defined inside

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationships.php
```